# Jquery.filer edit image get files on laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hei i am confused to get file from jquery files on edit...

i store my files on files plugin...

But i cannot get the file..

when i submit it just get null, using command laravel dd($request->file('files'))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#filer_input').filer({
    limit: 3,
    maxSize: 3,
    extensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "txt", "docx", "doc", "pdf"],
    showThumbs: true,
    addMore: true,
    files: [{
      name: "appended_file.jpg",
      size: 5453,
      type: "image/jpg",
      file: "https://dummyimage.com/158x113/f9f9f9/191a1a.jpg",
    }, {
      name: "appended_file_2.png",
      size: 9503,
      type: "image/png",
      file: "https://dummyimage.com/158x113/f9f9f9/191a1a.png",
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/epg_artikel/epg_edit_post')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-parsley-validate>


  <input type="file" name="files[]" id="filer_input" multiple="multiple">

  <input type="submit" />
```